# Can I panelize a field collection entity?

Tags: entities, panels

I have made a fieldable panel pane that uses a field collection to collect one or many pieces of content. I have included in the content a link to itself so that I can open the new content in it's "page".

What I need now is to be able to apply a panels template to that piece of content. I can use panelizer to apply templates to entities but it seems that field collections do not exist for it.

Is there a way to panelize a field collection entity or another away to approach my problem?